# Como usar varios onload en un mismo archivo html

Tags: javascript

A ver si me puede ayudar alguien.

Quiero usar en un archivo `html` varios scripts distintos en `vanilla javascript` y me encuentro con el problema de usar las funciones cuando esté cargado el documento con la instrucción :

```
document.onload = function (){
     ......
}
```

Al haber varios `onload` solo se ejecuta el último, por lo que no es lo que me gustaría.

¿Me recomiendan hacer algo?

Comment: ¿Me confundiste, "Me recomiendan hacer algo" es una pregunta, o falta algo en la frase?

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu pregunta, agregando el código que estás trabajando y el (o los) error(es) que tengas.

Comment: Y te da lo mismo en qué secuencia se ejecuten estas funciones?

Comment: En realidad debería existir un solo evento de **onload** en tu documento, si tu quieres hacer varias cosas cuando el documento se cargue ya eso debería ser responsabilidad de la lógica de tu aplicación.

Comment: Como te comentan es un evento y no tiene sentido que tengas diferentes onload todo lo que quieras hacer en el onload lo puedes meter en uno mismo.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente. Crea un solo evento `onload` que llame a una función que cargue las demás funciones.

Por ejemplo:

```
document.onload=cargarFunciones();
function cargarFunciones(){
   funcion1();
   funcion2();
   ....
}
```

Con esto puedes cargar diferentes funciones con el mismo `onload`.

Answer (score 0):

Como se comentó en otras respuestas deberías tener solo un `onload()` y puedes hacer que este dispare otras funciones que realizen ciertas tareas. 
Yo te recomendaría usar el patrón de Módulo Revelado (Revealing Module en ingles).

Puedes conseguir más información en [este enlace](http://www.etnassoft.com/2011/04/12/revealing-module-javascript/). Basicamente lo que hace este patrón es darle un espacio de nombre "namespacing" y poder modularizar todo para ejecutarlo justo cuando lo necesitas.

```
var miApp = ( function(){
  var metodoPrivado = function(){
    console.log( 'Privado: ', this);
    return 'Soy privado';
  }

  return {
    metodoPublico : function(){
      console.log( 'Publico: ', this);

      // Invocando el metodo privado:
      metodoPrivado();

      return 'Soy publico';
    }
  }
})();

miApp.metodoPublico();
```

Ojalá te sea de utilidad.

Saludos